# QuickBlox {"errors":["Unauthorized"]} during API Session Creation

Tags: quickblox

Since 6 month, I am using QuickBlox for chat application. But now I am facing unauthorised({"errors":["Unauthorized"]}) error in the response of API Session Creation. I cross verify with the credentials those are also correct. 
**Test Case**
1. Then I tried to create new application with the *SAME* QuickBlox account and used those(New Application) new Credentials, which work perfectly.

2. Moreover, I created new QuickBlox account and also create new Application. Again new application credentials also work perfectly.

**Issue**: Old Application is responding me with Unauthorized error.

**Facts**: I am using Free account but still not exceed with the limits.

**My Question**

1. QuickBlox didn't gave me any warning about my account. My QuickBlox account is blocked.? Is there any other issue.?

Answer (score 0):

I talked to QuickBlox team and finally they said, it was their bug.

Comment: did the QuickBlox team solve the issue? I have the same problem!

Comment: @hassanmoradnezhad I think, they(QuickBlox) eventually block free version account.